# Word that means "general preference to flee from/avoid commotion/attention"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, adverbs

Something that doesn't necessarily embody fear but cautiousness.

Contextually, this could relate to social environments.

A desire to remain in tranquil environments.

A general preference of calm environments.

A desire to not be the center of attention.

In general I am seeking a word that could be used to describe a person/animal/thing.

Comment: perhaps "peace-seeking" ?

Comment: You haven't quite made it clear whether you want a noun, a verb, an adjective or an adverb. Are you looking for one of those in particular? I ask because the title suggests a verb and the question refers to nouns.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - tweaked it a bit. hopefully it's not more confusing.

Comment: I would say the person "seeks solitude".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest **introverted**:

> Characterized by interest in or preoccupation with oneself or one's own thoughts as opposed to others or the environment; shy or reserved.

At least in the US, people typically describe others who would rather be by themselves than with others as introverted.

Source: [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/introverted)

Answer (score 3):

While it is somewhat more general, consider *[retire](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/retire)*

> to go away, as into seclusion, for recuperation, etc

*Collins*

Using it the context of the question, the term would likely be followed by an indication of what the person was avoiding or where he was going, such as

> *He retired from the cacophony of the of the dining table debate, seeking the sanctuary of his study.*

Comment: Or, if an adjective is desired, _retiring_.

Comment: This word does not describe a propensity, it describes an action.

Comment: @DaveMagner I think Doug Warren's supplement is a great suggestion, having much more characteristic about it.

Comment: @DougWarren In light of Dave Magner's comment, maybe you should make your comment an answer and give a definition, a cite and an example. I'd vote for it.

Answer (score 3):

Non-confrontational, meaning likes to avoid confrontation, disagreement.
Introverts are not out-going and generally like to keep to themselves, though this is usually applied to people.
Shy can be applied to animals as well.
For the cautious aspect skittish might apply.

Comment: +1 for _non-confrontational_. Fits the bill for this perfectly in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of avoiding attention I would go with [**shy**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shy?s=t), or if you'd like something more colloquial then a [**shrinking violet**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shrinking%20violet?s=t).

Neither of these really has the connotation of "flee" though; are you sure "flee" is the right word to describe what you want?

---

Definitions provided by dictionary.reference.com

Comment: flee or avoid (amended the question).

Comment: "avoid" = not seek out; "flee" = run as fast as can away from. They are very different things. "Fleeing" is not really avoiding commotion or attention - it's creating it. None of your examples have any connotation of "fleeing", hence why I think it may be the wrong word. If "flee" is definitely the right word then I've misunderstood the rest of the question, hence why I wanted to check.

Comment: well flee/leave in the sense of getting out of such an environment/situation if found to be in one and avoid in the sense of choosing not to join in such an environment/situation if observed beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

This person sounds a bit **monkish** but that word alone can easily imply a lot more than just what you list.

You can narrow it down a bit if you're willing to elaborate on...

```
his monkish withdrawal from the commotion of the modern world.
```

*Monastic* could also be used in that example and many others (especially when describing inanimate objects).

Definitions:

MONKISH ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monkish)):

```
of, relating to, or resembling a monk; also :  resembling that of a monk
```

MONASTIC ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monastic) second definition)

```
resembling (as in seclusion or ascetic simplicity) life in a monastery
```